Cannot boot after Ubuntu 24.04 recovery mode
Please help me saving my data on my hard drive. And please excuse me as I'm not an expert in Ubuntu but can follow instructions.
I have a lenovo ideapad 330 with 1 tera hdd that have dual boot of windows 10 and Ubuntu, Ubuntu is my main OS.
Last month I've encountered repeated problems while booting with the error "filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck" and by searching the problem I was able to solve it and it boots normally.
As Ubuntu 24.04 is out I thought it'll solve this problem for me so I did a clean installation of Ubuntu 24.04 along side windows 10.
Yesterday while using Ubuntu it suddenly freezes and didn't respond at all so I restarted it and choose the recovery mode, but it stuck again during that so I restarted it but it only gives me a blank screen.
I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but gparted cannot find my Hdd at all, it gives the error "error fsyncing/closing/dev/sda: input/output error" with each partition on my hdd.
BIOS can still see my Hdd but Ubuntu installation can not. I tried to boot windows but I get the error "Default boot Device Missing or Boot failed".
My HDD partitions is as follows:
Sda1 swap partition 14 gb
Sda2 ubuntu OS 149 gb
Sda3 entertainment 781 gb
Sda4 work 722 gb
Sda5 backup 165 gb
Sda6 EFI boot 100 mb
Sda7 win10 30 gb
I don't understand now, is my Hdd dead?! But how can Windows tries to repair itself?
Could you please help me? I really need to get the Hdd fixed it contains all my data and stupidly I don't have a backup for it.
Please help 
Update:
When I boot I can see the grub menu and When I try to enter the recovery mode of ubuntu it stuck at the first line:
Loading Linux 6.8.0.31-generic
Second update:
I realized that it freezes quickly at any stage even at BIOS!! It freezes even at Just pressing F10!
Please help!!
